# What does Non HTTP response message: Socket closed means?

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

What does Non HTTP response message: Socket closed means ?

During load test we see 30% of the time , call to third party failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [SocketException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/SocketException.html) and according to description:

> Thrown to indicate that there is an error creating or accessing a [Socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket).

In your situation this is the latter case and "Socket closed" means that JMeter either tries to send a message to the socket which has already been closed or attempts to read from the closed socket.

In the majority of cases the error indicates the problem with the **server** so you should not be worrying about JMeter side of things, however if you are **absolutely sure** that the system under test behaves correctly you can follow recommendations from [JMeterSocketClosed](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JMeterSocketClosed) wiki page where several workarounds are listed.

Also with regards to your "call to third party" stanza, ideally you should be focusing only on the domain(s) which is(are) related to the application you're testing, all 3rd-party stuff like images, banners, videos, maps, whatever should be excluded from your testing scope because:

- you might not be allowed to create excessive traffic for these components as it can be considered a [DoS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) attack
- even if you detect a problem with a 3rd-party component it won't be something you will be able to efficiently control or fix

See [Excluding Domains from the Load Test](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732519-Excluding-Domains-from-the-Load-Test-Excluding-Domains-from-the-Load-Test) article for more information and reasons for re-considering your approach